# In programmatically created ms-word file character encoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, character-encoding, ms-word

i'm retrieving text/html data from database that contains Turkish character set (ÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü) and i'm sending this data as microsoft word format as attached through email. The attached file seems properly when open with ms word older version (less than 2013) and open office but in ms word 2013, Turkish character that i specified above seems corrupt (in Arabic). As you can see below html code, i have added meta charachter set UTF-8, ISO-8859-9 and WINDOWS-1254  but there's nothing new. Meanwhile i'm attaching file as .doc because of opening older office version.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-9" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1254" />
        <title></title>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <xml><w:WordDocument><w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>112</w:Zoom><w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body lang=TR-TR style="tab-interval:.5in;font-family:Arial;">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;font-size:10.0pt;font-family:'Cambria','Arial','sans-serif';text-align:left;">
                ÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(db.GetDocFile(id));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress("from@domain.com");
        mail.To.Add("to@domain.com");
        mail.Subject = "";
        mail.Body = "";

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "mydocfile.doc");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com", 25))
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure UTF8 is the right encoding ? is Encoding.Unicode better for turkisch character set?  byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());

Comment: Unfortunately, it has corrupted.

Comment: could you save youre mail to disk, so you know where the problem is. In youre html or in the mail                <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\mail\"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>